# reinterpret_cast with a managed class

Tags: c++11

I want to write a managed class (ClassType^ ClassName) to a binary file and I want to know how to cast it. I tried the following code which does not work unfortunately:

```
outProjectfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ClassName), sizeof(ClassName));
```

Please can you help me?

Thanks

Abdoulaye

Comment: For which dialect do you have managed class? Is this c# rather than c++? If so, please tag it as c# so those experts look at it.

Comment: Hi @GemTaylor Thanks you for your response! Never minds ! It's working now! I figured out that the ClassName that was declared in the Winform managed area so i just need to create a another instance then copy the ClassName value into it.